# How to Integration of 4 digit pin in my app

Tags: android

In my Android app, I have to integrate 4 digit pin whenever user starts app if he is login.
If user is on dashboard and he close the app and when he reopen app next time app should ask for security pin. It should work on all activities.
How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wherever you are using the login authentication, save a key-value pair in SharedPreferences. For example, in LoginActivity, if all credentials are same,
use :

```
SharedPrefernces sp = getSharedPreferences("PreferenceFile",MODE_PRIVATE);
sp.edit().putBoolean("isLoggedIn",true).apply();
sp.edit().putBoolean("Password",1234).apply();
```

And then redirect user to MainActivity/Dashboard.

Now in any activity where you want to have security pin checking, just get the text from user, and check:

```
SharedPrefernces sp = getSharedPreferences("PreferenceFile",MODE_PRIVATE);
sp.getBoolean("isLoggedIn",false);
String checker = sp.getBoolean("Password",0);

if( (editText.getText().toString().trim()).equals(checker) ) {
    //Do Secure Work
} else  {
    //Add warning Toast
}
```

For extra checking that the activity has started because of intent or it came from background, you can have an isBack variable.

In Any Activity, use

```
onCreate() {
    isBack = false;
}
onStop() {
    isBack = true;
}
```

Then in onStart, you can use

```
onStart() {
    if(isBack) {
        // Do the work which you want to do if the activity comes from background
    } else {
        // Do the work which you want to do if activity comes due to any intent
    }
    // After doing all the necessary work, remember to update isBack 
    // because now the activity is in focus
    isBack = false;
}
```

Comment: I don't want this. User log in first time, then app will ask him to set pin. No suppose he is on any activity in app and close the app, so when he open app next time previous activity will start, here app should ask pin. This is what I need

Comment: First Thing- Are you asking about closing app or sending it to background?Because if you close the activity, next time the launcher activity will start only, not the one you closed and hence you can ask for pin in launcher activity everytime. If you are talking about sending it to background, then you can ask for the pin on every activity's onStart method. Because when we send app in background, onStop is called and when it again gains focus, onStart method is called. So, you can use AlertDialog on onStart method which asks for PIN if app goes background.

Comment: But onstart method will also run when user will move from one activity to another. How could I check if activity open from background?

Comment: I guess if you always check it on onStart, then when your activity is created,then prompt will be asked, and if it is from background, then too it will be asked. This is what you want. So just use the structure on onStart of the activities. As an alternate, you can keep record of it by using a boolean isBg. In onCreate, make isBg=false. in onStop, make it true. And in onStart check if isBg is true,means it came from background, if it is false, it means the activity is just created and never been to background. And after checking the 4-digit password, set isBg back = false.

Comment: I added the necessary conditions which were required for extra check. If the answer meets your requirements, do accept it.

Comment: Okay and what will happen when user terminate (end task) app? Will onStop will get called?

Comment: Yup. The activity life cycle goes like - > On calling intent of an activity,onCreate is called only once. Then onStart and onResume is called. When there is an external call, for example , we share something from app, or fetch an image from device, onPause is called and a picker is called(eg. Camera, Gallery,Files etc.).If we tap on anything, onStop is called and we are sent to that app.Then when we get back, onStart and onResume is called.If we send app to back then onPause() and then onStop() happens.When we end task or terminate, then onPause(),onStop(),onDestroy() is called.Hence it works.